# Merging 2 tables adding variable DV01 by Date using R

Tags: r, merge, left-join, group

what's the best way to do the procedure below using R?

I have these two tables and the idea it's to group the variable DV01 by fixing date on the second table. So since the dates doesn't match I need to sum the DV01 between the fixing dates and merge it on the second table.

The final result should be the second table including a new column DV01 added by contract.

#this first table is and example, since the original have more than 100k rows.

| DT_VCTO | DV01 |
| --- | --- |
| 1/5/2023 | 0 |
| 11/5/2023 | -0.04 |
| 3/5/2025 | -0.08 |
| 9/5/2025 | -0.07 |
| 1/5/2026 | -0.08 |
| 3/10/2023 | 0 |
| 1/5/2023 | 0 |
| 1/5/2023 | 0 |
| 6/5/2023 | -0.01 |
| 6/5/2023 | 0 |
| 2/5/2023 | -0.01 |
| 3/5/2024 | -0.04 |
| 6/5/2024 | -0.06 |
| 1/5/2025 | -0.07 |
| 12/5/2025 | -0.08 |
| 6/5/2023 | -0.01 |
| 9/5/2023 | -0.02 |
| 11/5/2023 | -0.02 |
| 4/5/2023 | 0 |
| 5/5/2023 | 0 |
| 9/5/2023 | -0.03 |
| 12/5/2023 | -0.04 |
| 7/5/2024 | -0.06 |

And this second one which include the futures contracts from B3:

| symbol | price_previous | price | change | fixing | adjusted_tax | DV01_CTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DI1F23 | 99796.97 | 99796.98 | 0.01 | 2023-01-02 | 0.13659 | -0.14 |
| DI1G23 | 98687.03 | 98688.07 | 1.04 | 2023-02-01 | 0.13655 | -0.9 |
| DI1H23 | 97786.97 | 97786.91 | -0.06 | 2023-03-01 | 0.13675 | -1.5 |
| DI1J23 | 96644.95 | 96644.66 | -0.29 | 2023-04-03 | 0.13697 | -2.26 |
| DI1K23 | 95752.06 | 95752.62 | 0.56 | 2023-05-02 | 0.13732 | -2.84 |
| DI1M23 | 94666.68 | 94668.52 | 1.84 | 2023-06-01 | 0.13773 | -3.53 |
| DI1N23 | 93653.91 | 93657.68 | 3.77 | 2023-07-03 | 0.13769 | -4.18 |
| DI1Q23 | 92650.52 | 92657.22 | 6.7 | 2023-08-01 | 0.13767 | -4.82 |
| DI1U23 | 91576.32 | 91587.12 | 10.8 | 2023-09-01 | 0.13741 | -5.5 |
| DI1V23 | 90658.14 | 90673 | 14.86 | 2023-10-02 | 0.13713 | -6.07 |
| DI1X23 | 89717.69 | 89735.19 | 17.5 | 2023-11-01 | 0.13671 | -6.67 |
| DI1Z23 | 88845.3 | 88864.82 | 19.52 | 2023-12-01 | 0.13619 | -7.23 |
| DI1F24 | 88006.43 | 88027.2 | 20.77 | 2024-01-02 | 0.13544 | -7.78 |
| DI1J24 | 85469.38 | 85502.54 | 33.16 | 2024-04-01 | 0.13394 | -9.39 |
| DI1N24 | 83011.86 | 83056.79 | 44.93 | 2024-07-01 | 0.13212 | -10.97 |
| DI1V24 | 80534.85 | 80572.14 | 37.29 | 2024-10-01 | 0.13075 | -12.52 |
| DI1F25 | 78261.21 | 78284.41 | 23.2 | 2025-01-02 | 0.1294 | -13.94 |
| DI1J25 | 76044.4 | 76051.56 | 7.16 | 2025-04-01 | 0.12914 | -15.18 |
| DI1N25 | 73853.35 | 73859.61 | 6.26 | 2025-07-01 | 0.12907 | -16.33 |
| DI1V25 | 71518.64 | 71520.32 | 1.68 | 2025-10-01 | 0.12923 | -17.46 |
| DI1F26 | 69338.9 | 69326 | -12.9 | 2026-01-02 | 0.12916 | -18.51 |
| DI1J26 | 67307.25 | 67270.6 | -36.65 | 2026-04-01 | 0.1294 | -19.4 |
| DI1N26 | 65347.98 | 65281.56 | -66.42 | 2026-07-01 | 0.12958 | -20.22 |
| DI1V26 | 63337.09 | 63282.81 | -54.28 | 2026-10-01 | 0.12948 | -21.05 |
| DI1F27 | 61461.24 | 61405.16 | -56.08 | 2027-01-04 | 0.12939 | -21.79 |
| DI1J27 | 59740.83 | 59667.42 | -73.41 | 2027-04-01 | 0.12932 | -22.43 |
| DI1N27 | 57953.6 | 57869.08 | -84.52 | 2027-07-01 | 0.12937 | -23.03 |
| DI1V27 | 56186.79 | 56088.39 | -98.4 | 2027-10-01 | 0.12934 | -23.6 |
| DI1F28 | 54501.64 | 54408.51 | -93.13 | 2028-01-03 | 0.12934 | -24.1 |
| DI1F29 | 48291.85 | 48167.79 | -124.06 | 2029-01-02 | 0.12965 | -25.54 |
| DI1F30 | 42914.94 | 42723.09 | -191.85 | 2030-01-02 | 0.12949 | -26.41 |
| DI1F31 | 37955.22 | 37790.81 | -164.41 | 2031-01-02 | 0.12955 | -26.71 |
| DI1F32 | 33695.24 | 33525.65 | -169.59 | 2032-01-02 | 0.12923 | -26.68 |
| DI1F33 | 29826.72 | 29625.97 | -200.75 | 2033-01-03 | 0.12947 | -26.2 |
| DI1F34 | 26466.52 | 26270.75 | -195.77 | 2034-01-02 | 0.12936 | -25.55 |
| DI1F35 | 23531.97 | 23342.33 | -189.64 | 2035-01-02 | 0.12917 | -24.74 |
| DI1F36 | 20838.15 | 20656.44 | -181.71 | 2036-01-02 | 0.12932 | -23.71 |
| DI1F37 | 18401.01 | 18228.23 | -172.78 | 2037-01-02 | 0.12952 | -22.54 |

I've tried to sum a group the DV01 by fixing dat, but couldn't use left join + groupby using tow conditions simultaneously since you need to consider that the DT_VCTO should be higher than the fixing date before and lower or equal the next fixing date.

#The final table should be like this one and can be easly obtained using excel, for example:

| symbol | price_previous | price | change | fixing | adjusted_tax | DV01_CTO | DV01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DI1F23 | 99796.97 | 99796.98 | 0.01 | 1/2/2023 | 0.136590066 | -0.14 | 0 |
| DI1G23 | 98687.03 | 98688.07 | 1.04 | 2/1/2023 | 0.136550458 | -0.9 | 0 |
| DI1H23 | 97786.97 | 97786.91 | -0.06 | 3/1/2023 | 0.136749968 | -1.5 | -0.01 |
| DI1J23 | 96644.95 | 96644.66 | -0.29 | 4/3/2023 | 0.136969815 | -2.26 | 0 |
| DI1K23 | 95752.06 | 95752.62 | 0.56 | 5/2/2023 | 0.137320144 | -2.84 | 0 |
| DI1M23 | 94666.68 | 94668.52 | 1.84 | 6/1/2023 | 0.137729913 | -3.53 | 0 |
| DI1N23 | 93653.91 | 93657.68 | 3.77 | 7/3/2023 | 0.137689998 | -4.18 | -0.02 |
| DI1Q23 | 92650.52 | 92657.22 | 6.7 | 8/1/2023 | 0.137669919 | -4.82 | 0 |
| DI1U23 | 91576.32 | 91587.12 | 10.8 | 9/1/2023 | 0.137409989 | -5.5 | 0 |
| DI1V23 | 90658.14 | 90673 | 14.86 | 10/2/2023 | 0.137130072 | -6.07 | -0.05 |
| DI1X23 | 89717.69 | 89735.19 | 17.5 | 11/1/2023 | 0.136709948 | -6.67 | 0 |
| DI1Z23 | 88845.3 | 88864.82 | 19.52 | 12/1/2023 | 0.136189996 | -7.23 | -0.06 |
| DI1F24 | 88006.43 | 88027.2 | 20.77 | 1/2/2024 | 0.135440044 | -7.78 | -0.04 |
| DI1J24 | 85469.38 | 85502.54 | 33.16 | 4/1/2024 | 0.133940035 | -9.39 | -0.04 |
| DI1N24 | 83011.86 | 83056.79 | 44.93 | 7/1/2024 | 0.132120039 | -10.97 | -0.06 |
| DI1V24 | 80534.85 | 80572.14 | 37.29 | 10/1/2024 | 0.13075002 | -12.52 | -0.06 |
| DI1F25 | 78261.21 | 78284.41 | 23.2 | 1/2/2025 | 0.129400013 | -13.94 | 0 |
| DI1J25 | 76044.4 | 76051.56 | 7.16 | 4/1/2025 | 0.129140027 | -15.18 | -0.15 |
| DI1N25 | 73853.35 | 73859.61 | 6.26 | 7/1/2025 | 0.129070031 | -16.33 | 0 |
| DI1V25 | 71518.64 | 71520.32 | 1.68 | 10/1/2025 | 0.129230021 | -17.46 | -0.07 |
| DI1F26 | 69338.9 | 69326 | -12.9 | 1/2/2026 | 0.129160012 | -18.51 | -0.08 |
| DI1J26 | 67307.25 | 67270.6 | -36.65 | 4/1/2026 | 0.129399981 | -19.4 | -0.08 |
| DI1N26 | 65347.98 | 65281.56 | -66.42 | 7/1/2026 | 0.129579997 | -20.22 | 0 |
| DI1V26 | 63337.09 | 63282.81 | -54.28 | 10/1/2026 | 0.12948002 | -21.05 | 0 |
| DI1F27 | 61461.24 | 61405.16 | -56.08 | 1/4/2027 | 0.12938999 | -21.79 | 0 |
| DI1J27 | 59740.83 | 59667.42 | -73.41 | 4/1/2027 | 0.129319999 | -22.43 | 0 |
| DI1N27 | 57953.6 | 57869.08 | -84.52 | 7/1/2027 | 0.129369987 | -23.03 | 0 |
| DI1V27 | 56186.79 | 56088.39 | -98.4 | 10/1/2027 | 0.129340016 | -23.6 | 0 |
| DI1F28 | 54501.64 | 54408.51 | -93.13 | 1/3/2028 | 0.129339996 | -24.1 | 0 |
| DI1F29 | 48291.85 | 48167.79 | -124.06 | 1/2/2029 | 0.129650013 | -25.54 | 0 |
| DI1F30 | 42914.94 | 42723.09 | -191.85 | 1/2/2030 | 0.129490006 | -26.41 | 0 |
| DI1F31 | 37955.22 | 37790.81 | -164.41 | 1/2/2031 | 0.129549983 | -26.71 | 0 |
| DI1F32 | 33695.24 | 33525.65 | -169.59 | 1/2/2032 | 0.12923001 | -26.68 | 0 |
| DI1F33 | 29826.72 | 29625.97 | -200.75 | 1/3/2033 | 0.129470016 | -26.2 | 0 |
| DI1F34 | 26466.52 | 26270.75 | -195.77 | 1/2/2034 | 0.129360016 | -25.55 | 0 |
| DI1F35 | 23531.97 | 23342.33 | -189.64 | 1/2/2035 | 0.129169999 | -24.74 | 0 |
| DI1F36 | 20838.15 | 20656.44 | -181.71 | 1/2/2036 | 0.12932 | -23.71 | 0 |
| DI1F37 | 18401.01 | 18228.23 | -172.78 | 1/2/2037 | 0.129519986 | -22.54 | 0 |

Comment: Well, first of all you don't have dates in the first frame, you have (not unambiguous) strings. I'm inferrring `df1$DT_VCTO <- as.Date(df1$DT_VCTO, format="%m/%d/%Y")`, but I'm not certain.

Comment: It seems like this is a join on range, but since the first frame is not in order, I can't assume or safely infer that. It would help if you had expected values, perhaps as a manually-entered additional column in your second frame.

Comment: I thinks the conversion from date to string it happened after saving the frame as xlsx.

Since the original data I'll have more than 100k rows, the best approach should rank first by date the first data frame?

the process that I want to replicate using R can be done easly on excel using SUMIFs, for example.

Comment: Okay, I'll try a different tact. Is your `DV01_CTO` somehow based off of the `DV01` values in your first table? If so, how?  Your first table values don't go near as high (in magnitude) as in the second table.

Comment: I'm guessing that you somehow lost the stock symbols for the first file and now need to go back and fix that problem.

Comment: @r2evans they are not related. Since the second table shows the derivatives that I can negotiate, I just want to know  where the accumulated dv01 from table 1 would be allocated in the second one.

Comment: I've included the expected result, but the idea it's to reproduce it using R.